# Laravel Stuck getting last user who posted in forum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I have a basic forum set up and I have the relationships between models completed. However I am stuck trying to get the last user who posted in the sub category. This is how its laid out.

mysql tables
forum_category (this is used for the main category and also the sub category)
forum_post (this is used for the posts)

Here is my **ForumCategory.php**

```
namespace App\Models\Forum;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ForumCategory extends Model {

    protected $table = 'forum_category';

    public static function category()
    {
        return ForumCategory::with('ForumSubCategory')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
    }
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function ForumSubCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Forum\ForumSubCategory' , 'parent_id');
    }
    public function ForumPost()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Forum\ForumPost' , 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

And here is my **ForumSubCategory.php** the sub category model even though they are using the same table...

```
namespace App\Models\Forum;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ForumSubCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'forum_category';

    public function ForumCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Forum\ForumCategory');
    }
    public function User()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function ForumPost()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Forum\ForumPost' , 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

And here Is my **ForumPost.php** model

```
namespace App\Models\Forum;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ForumPost extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'forum_post';

    public function User()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function ForumSubCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Forum\ForumSubCategory');
    }
}
```

The controller is pretty basic, the index is

```
public function index() {
   return view('forum.index', ['category' => ForumCategory::category()]);
}
```

Now at the moment I am currently getting my last user who posted with this

```
public static function LastPost($value)
{
    $lastPost = ForumPost::whereParentId($value)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->pluck('user_id')->first();
    return User::whereId($lastPost)->pluck('username')->first();
}
```

Which I DO NOT want to do. I want to know the correct way of doing this :(

Here is my view

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($category as $cat)
    <li>
        {{$cat->category_name}} - this is main category
        {{$cat->category_description}} - this is main category description

        @if ($cat->ForumSubCategory)
        <ul>
            @foreach ($cat->ForumSubCategory as $sub)
                <li>
                    <a href="/forum/{{$cat->slug}}/{{$sub->slug}}">  - this is the category slug with the sub category slug
                        {{$sub->category_name}} - this is the sub category name
                    </a>
                    {{$sub->category_description}} - this is the sub category description
                    {{$sub->ForumPost->count()}} - this is how many posts are in the sub category
                    {{$sub->LastPost($sub->id)}} - this is how i am currently getting the last user who posted
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        @endif
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution:

You can filter/order relationships, hence the function below.

`latest()` is an eloquent shortcut for `orderBy('created_at','DESC')`

**ForumSubCategory Model:**

```
class ForumSubCategory extends Model
{
    ...
    public function latestPost()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Forum\ForumPost' , 'parent_id')->latest()->with('user');
    }
}
```

**In your view:**

From:

```
{{$sub->LastPost($sub->id)}} - this is how i am currently getting the last user who posted
```

To:

```
@if($sub->latestPost) 
    @if($sub->latestPost->user)
        {{$sub->latestPost->user->username or 'Username not set'}}
    @else
       {{'User Not Found'}}
    @endif
@else 
   {{'No Last Post'}}
@endif
```

The most stable solution should be a service class around forum sub categories to take care of edge cases such as users being deleted, posts banned and so forth.

Comment: Thank you, It displays when i do {{$sub->latestPost}} it returns the user data and all, just having an error when i try to target any data inside of it eg {{$sub->latestPost->id or even user->username it returns Trying to get property of non-object  >_< ill keep googling ^_^

Comment: `Property of non-object` means you don't have a `latestPost` object. or even a user set on the latest post. Included a complete solution to those cases.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!! this has been messing with my head for so long its not even funny. yes that's how slow I am!

Comment: We all have to start somewhere. Have fun with laravel :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of dynamic properties. Check out [Relationship Methods Vs Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

```
// Controller
public function lastPost()
{
    $lastPost = ForumPost::whereParentId($value)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

    $username = $lastPost->user->username;

    return view('post.view', compact('username'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!. I will take a look at Dynamic Properties, But just a quick question: So I would set up a new function for lastPost and then in the blade just do {{$lastPost->user->username}} ?

Comment: @Unifx I've edited my answer, add that method inside your controller. Then access the username on your view {{username}}

Comment: Thanks but I dont think this is what I was after and also It does not work